# AddressSanitizer: DEADLYSIGNAL

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, binary-search, function-definition

I cannot figure out the cause of this error.

```
int binarySearch(int* arr,int l,int r,int x){
    int mid = (l+r)/2;
    if(arr[mid]==x){
        return mid;
    }
    else if(arr[mid]>x){
        binarySearch(arr,mid,r,x);
    }
    else if(arr[mid]<x){
        binarySearch(arr,l,mid,x);
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int search(int* nums, int numsSize, int target){
    return binarySearch(nums,0,numsSize-1,target);
}
```

This is simple binary search program.
This is the error.

```
==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffdbdd5cff8 (pc 0x55745fa9be6c bp 0x7ffdbdd5d010 sp 0x7ffdbdd5d000 T0)
==30==ABORTING
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: You don't have termination condition if the element isn't found in one of the subarrays.

Comment: Suppose no element of the array actually equals x. What return statement could you actually hit with the control flow in your program?

Comment: Could you please move the error message into your question's body (ideally formatted as code) and change the title to something more descriptive and general (perhaps something with "error", "AddressSanitizer", or "stack-overflow", but without the hex codes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters i t seems due to a typo the first function parameter has an incorrect type. The function should be declared at least like

```
int binarySearch( const int arr[], int l, int r, int x );
```

The function does not stop to call itself recursively if the target element is not equal to an element in the array.

Also if `arr[mid]` is greater than `x` then all values in the range  `[mid, r]` obviously also will be greater than `x`. So the sub-statement of the of statement

```
else if(arr[mid]>x){
    binarySearch(arr,mid,r,x);
}
```

is incorrect,

Using your approach the function definition can look the following way

```
int binarySearch( const int arr[], int l, int r, int x )
{
    if ( !( r < l ) )
    {
        int mid = l + ( r - l ) / 2;

        if( arr[mid] == x )
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if ( x < arr[mid] )
        {
            return binarySearch( arr, l, mid - 1, x );
        }
        else
        {
            return binarySearch( arr, mid + 1, r, x );
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Pay attention to that the searched array must be sorted.